# Ubuntu 19.04 installation only detect one partition need help!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

so i wan't to install Ubuntu on my laptop with dual booting but it seems i can't get it work some how ubuntu didn't detect my windows 10 but then when i click *something else* there's only one partition which is the whole drive, but there's 4 partition on windows and i tried almost everything i could find by turning off fast boot, fix drive c:, disabling UEFI boot.[whole disk detetcted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qImLj.png) but gparted detect all of'em while opening gparted it says *"cant have overlapping partition"*[gparted somehow detect 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhsVV.png)

Comment: You have BIOS boot or CSM if UEFI system. And then MBR(msdos) partitioning.  Fast start up is most common issue. But it could also be that the NTFS needs chkdsk. Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, so double check that it is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: In looking at your gparted screenshot, your partitioning is currently a disaster. You have over 200G of unallocated space spread out of 3 different areas on your smallish 500G HDD. I'd wipe the disk and reinstall everything (prefer UEFI/GPT over BIOS/MBR)... Windows first, or spend a whole lot of time manually moving partitions around.